# Output 20 More data

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that will display 20 more data or else exit the loop. The big issue is with confirm because I want the user to input either Y or N. How can I fix this?

```
void DisplayData(int StartIndex, int EndIndex)

char confirm = 0;
while (confirm != 'n' || 'N')
{
    int index = 1;
    for (index = StartIndex; index < EndIndex; index++)
    {
        printf("%d. %d.%d.%d.%d => %d.%d.%d.%d | ", index, sourceIP[index][0], sourceIP[index][1], sourceIP[index][2], sourceIP[index][3],
            destinationIP[index][0], destinationIP[index][1], destinationIP[index][2], destinationIP[index][3]);



        if (protocol[index][3] == 0)
        {
            printf("%c%c%c", protocol[index][0], protocol[index][1], protocol[index][2]);
        }
        else if (protocol[index][4] == 0)
        {
            printf("%c%c%c%c", protocol[index][0], protocol[index][1], protocol[index][2], protocol[index][3]);
        }

        printf("| %d | %d\n", source_port[index], destination_port[index]);
    }

    printf("Display More: <Y>ES | <N>O: ");
    scanf("%c", &confirm);

    if (confirm == 'y' || confirm == 'Y')
    {
        StartIndex += 20;
    }
    else if (confirm == 'n' || 'N')
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Input");

    }

}
```

Comment: Probably better if you post this in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. move `int index = 1;` up and out of while loop
2. replace `StartIndex += 20;` with `EndIndex += 20;`
3. and replace the

   ```
   (confirm == 'n' || 'N')
   ```

   with

   ```
   (confirm == 'n' || confirm == 'N')
   ```
4. i presume you missing a `{` from the first of function under signature or it's just a typo.